# conda create --name py36 python=3.6 frozen

Tags: anaconda

I'm trying to upgrade python 2.7 to python 3.6 in anaconda via

```
conda create --name py36 python=3.6
```

However, it's been stuck at this for 10 minutes:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda create --name py36 python=3.6
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
```

I tried it while running as administrator and while not running as administrator and I get the same result either way.

Also, I'm using a Windows 10 PC.

This is what I get when I enter conda info.

```
 active environment : base
active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2
        shell level : 1
   user config file : C:\Users\lamei\.condarc
  populated config files :
      conda version : 4.7.5
conda-build version : 3.18.7
     python version : 2.7.16.final.0
   virtual packages :
   base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2  (read only)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
      package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs
                      C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs
                      C:\Users\lamei\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\Users\lamei\.conda\envs
                      C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs
                      C:\Users\lamei\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

Typing in `conda create -vv --name py36 python=3.6` gets me stuck at this.

```
(base) C:\Users\lamei>conda create -vv --name py36 python=3.6
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(231): verbosity set to 2
DEBUG conda.base.context:root_writable(412): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\conda-meta\\history'
DEBUG conda.base.context:root_writable(412): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\conda-meta\\history'
DEBUG conda.base.context:root_writable(412): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\conda-meta\\history'
DEBUG conda.base.context:root_writable(412): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\conda-meta\\history'
DEBUG conda.base.context:root_writable(412): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\conda-meta\\history'
DEBUG conda.base.context:root_writable(412): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\conda-meta\\history'
DEBUG conda.core.solve:solve_final_state(216): solving prefix C:\Users\lamei\.conda\envs\py36
  specs_to_remove: frozenset([])
  specs_to_add: frozenset([MatchSpec("python=3.6")])
  prune: <auxlib._Null object at 0x00000000036F4EF0>
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.test:file_path_is_writable(31): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\pkgs\\urls.txt'
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(261): package cache directory 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs' writable: False
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(261): package cache directory 'C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs' writable: True
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(225): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json at C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\e915db84.json
DEBUG urllib3.util.retry:from_int(210): Converted retries value: 3 -> Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_new_conn(813): Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(393): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(471):
>>GET /pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> If-Modified-Since: Sun, 19 May 2019 04:48:46 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"917338f97423c09c911618661fef3056"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 1393958
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 4f4cf500aa5aab6a-YYZ
< Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:23 GMT
< ETag: "917338f97423c09c911618661fef3056"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:53 GMT
< Last-Modified: Sun, 19 May 2019 04:48:46 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d2bf40df048b0a54bb77b3e51ff90dc231562870963; expires=Fri, 10-Jul-20 18:49:23 GMT; path=/; domain=.anaconda.com; HttpOnly; Secure
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: WHa4A/RaAmx9hfaasy3WiOBbOmf8cgDKKdaVAM48ffP/U3C09WEeF1wGRuI8318+EgyuE8mgs4M=
< x-amz-request-id: 8C8B0D6B1FFA5B5C
< x-amz-version-id: E.MdSxPa2LBJzubeZccSKcYHuTe2sqfi
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:03.304343


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(244): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch/current_repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(308): found pickle file C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\e915db84.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(225): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json at C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\1394f696.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(393): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(471):
>>GET /pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cookie: __cfduid=d2bf40df048b0a54bb77b3e51ff90dc231562870963
> If-Modified-Since: Sun, 19 May 2019 04:48:47 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"e37881523af65bd1f349cc4f2557a6a1"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 1393958
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 4f4cf5015b03ab6a-YYZ
< Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:23 GMT
< ETag: "e37881523af65bd1f349cc4f2557a6a1"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:53 GMT
< Last-Modified: Sun, 19 May 2019 04:48:47 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: FcPx2rFXp1HZXyd5uVel0Ug+0dGOqAjMcqVL7bss9lcx+yohIZadTg9EtEjU0qCiGRLg4rVOiXw=
< x-amz-request-id: 8E75CF9EE3C06BED
< x-amz-version-id: JU4iMc.hWsVB2rI79j_OokHes10knsjP
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.033039


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(244): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64/current_repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(308): found pickle file C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\1394f696.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(225): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json at C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\227b7582.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(393): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(471):
>>GET /pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cookie: __cfduid=d2bf40df048b0a54bb77b3e51ff90dc231562870963
> If-Modified-Since: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 22:47:30 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"3f33bb28f4736a6669785b9ee4d38db0"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 1444707
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 4f4cf5022be9ab6a-YYZ
< Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:23 GMT
< ETag: "3f33bb28f4736a6669785b9ee4d38db0"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:53 GMT
< Last-Modified: Mon, 24 Jun 2019 22:47:30 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: EB3JGlvdo72yZ+xA5OkeW2YKl4GfR1MuOzLHY+4IzyL0uLTyWMpl380qiwtjuPiXzZSTPqhX7RU=
< x-amz-request-id: C243BC765C14D8B8
< x-amz-version-id: mADTW9JTJbbrwPus3I7stfLJBzgi_yJy
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.030598


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(244): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/current_repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(308): found pickle file C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\227b7582.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(225): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json at C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\a9664645.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(393): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(471):
>>GET /pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cookie: __cfduid=d2bf40df048b0a54bb77b3e51ff90dc231562870963
> If-Modified-Since: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 19:50:04 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"9cdacec2edd24dc16ae8d85ef2f9b44c"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 1375334
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 4f4cf5030d08ab6a-YYZ
< Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:23 GMT
< ETag: "9cdacec2edd24dc16ae8d85ef2f9b44c"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:53 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 19:50:04 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: NXonvH8FUrJMkNisTyGODHlu1e2wPrcaXn7UNvdTWv3zVzbbY+DqfCdXsSCQR1nx+JfE8HHnoSQ=
< x-amz-request-id: 968302B7283965DE
< x-amz-version-id: nBF.V6Lk.eFofKCObPpzwdG1RgOYh9KC
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.030314


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(244): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64/current_repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(308): found pickle file C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\a9664645.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(225): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json at C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\b35683e8.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(393): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(471):
>>GET /pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cookie: __cfduid=d2bf40df048b0a54bb77b3e51ff90dc231562870963
> If-Modified-Since: Tue, 09 Jul 2019 20:23:09 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"08cced9cae993c8e0957d14345acd6eb"

<<HTTPS 304 Not Modified
< Age: 166824
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 4f4cf504beccab6a-YYZ
< Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:23 GMT
< ETag: "08cced9cae993c8e0957d14345acd6eb"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:53 GMT
< Last-Modified: Tue, 09 Jul 2019 20:23:09 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: hbbMhtQLoTfhBH3YzeJ9vrT4oke+hfMMQ2jYZdRZYZhhuegBNwfGhNQsRU8yOwtfu5vZj0g/0UM=
< x-amz-request-id: 7244A0811407191F
< x-amz-version-id: oH.QZZzx7eNc7WFofmJZ2wyO4Rb5Dbda
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.025985


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(244): 304 NOT MODIFIED for 'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch/current_repodata.json'. Updating mtime and loading from disk
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_read_pickled(308): found pickle file C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\b35683e8.q
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_load(225): Local cache timed out for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json at C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\9b8cd901.json
DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool:_make_request(393): https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:fetch_repodata_remote_request(471):
>>GET /pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json HTTPS
> User-Agent: conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.16 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17763
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress, identity
> Connection: keep-alive
> Content-Type: application/json
> Cookie: __cfduid=d2bf40df048b0a54bb77b3e51ff90dc231562870963
> If-Modified-Since: Wed, 10 Jul 2019 02:43:51 GMT
> If-None-Match: W/"3774009418d6658d39bc4b6682dae00a"

<<HTTPS 200 OK
< Age: 12897
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=30
< CF-Cache-Status: HIT
< CF-RAY: 4f4cf5055f6dab6a-YYZ
< Content-Encoding: gzip
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:24 GMT
< ETag: W/"0aed51b2df88ae85c6aeefc58b5fdb1b"
< Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
< Expires: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 18:49:54 GMT
< Last-Modified: Thu, 11 Jul 2019 15:12:40 GMT
< Server: cloudflare
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< x-amz-id-2: XwzU9FJ5SZX/kR2+M8LAwU9S5+YrVppI6LM93+Np1yL9871PW0yhIkVfJLaNz1XdQe/0X0l4HmU=
< x-amz-request-id: 23FECC4905751AD5
< x-amz-version-id: 1iXEmvXZ5bRiHMRMwQJdBSrZdd611STx
< Connection: keep-alive
< Elapsed: 00:00.049010

{ u'info': { u'subdir': u'win-64'},
  u'packages': { u'bzip2-1.0.7-h0c8e037_0.tar.bz2': { u'build': u'h0c8e037_0',
                                                      u'build_number': 0,
                                                      u'depends': [


DEBUG conda.core.subdir_data:_pickle_me(268): Saving pickled state for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json at C:\Users\lamei\.conda\pkgs\cache\9b8cd901.json
done
Solving environment: ...working... DEBUG conda.resolve:get_reduced_index(483): Retrieving packages for:
  - python=3.6
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): python: pruned from 7 -> 3
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): pip: pruned from 6 -> 2
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): wheel: pruned from 6 -> 2
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): setuptools: pruned from 6 -> 2
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): certifi: pruned from 6 -> 2
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): wincertstore: pruned from 4 -> 1
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): vc: pruned from 4 -> 2
DEBUG conda.resolve:filter_group(544): sqlite: pruned from 4 -> 2
DEBUG conda.core.solve:_add_specs(537): specs_map with targets: OrderedDict()
DEBUG conda.resolve:bad_installed(1017): Checking if the current environment is consistent
DEBUG conda.core.solve:_find_inconsistent_packages(369): inconsistent precs: None
DEBUG conda.core.solve:_run_sat(681): final specs to add:
  - python=3.6
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1143): Solving for:
  - python=3.6
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1150): Solve: Getting reduced index of compliant packages
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1160): Solve: determining satisfiability
DEBUG conda.resolve:_get_sat_solver_cls(50): Using SAT solver interface 'pycosat'.
DEBUG conda.resolve:gen_clauses(822): gen_clauses returning with clause count: 104
DEBUG conda.resolve:generate_spec_constraints(830): generate_spec_constraints returning with clause count: 104
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 105
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1207): Solve: minimize removed packages
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1214): Solve: maximize versions of requested packages
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1218): Initial package channel/version metric: 0/0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1221): Solve: minimize track_feature count
DEBUG conda.resolve:generate_feature_count(838): generate_feature_count returning with clause count: 108
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(776): Clauses added, recomputing solution
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 108
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 109
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 109
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(862): Final sum objective: 1
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(874): New peak objective: 1
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1224): Track feature count: 1
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1235): Package misfeature count: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1238): Solve: maximize build numbers of requested packages
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 111
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(862): Final peak objective: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1240): Initial package build metric: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1243): Solve: prefer arch over noarch for requested packages
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1245): Noarch metric: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1249): Solve: minimize number of optional installations
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1252): Optional package install metric: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1255): Solve: minimize number of necessary upgrades
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1258): Dependency update count: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1261): Solve: maximize versions and builds of indirect dependencies.  Prefer arch over noarch where equivalent.
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 116
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(862): Final sum objective: 0
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 117
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(862): Final sum objective: 0
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(782): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1269): Additional package channel/version/build/noarch metrics: 0/0/0/0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1272): Solve: prune unnecessary packages
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 125
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 132
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(862): Final sum objective: 8
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(874): New peak objective: 1
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1275): Weak dependency count: 8
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 133
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 133
DEBUG conda.common.logic:minimize(862): Final sum objective: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1281): Timestamp metric: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1283): Looking for alternate solutions
DEBUG conda.common.logic:_run_sat(705): Invoking SAT with clause count: 134
done
DEBUG conda.core.solve:solve_final_state(265): solved prefix C:\Users\lamei\.conda\envs\py36
  solved_linked_dists:
    defaults::vs2015_runtime-14.15.26706-h3a45250_4
    defaults::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
    defaults::sqlite-3.28.0-he774522_0
    defaults::python-3.6.8-h9f7ef89_7
    defaults::certifi-2019.6.16-py36_0
    defaults::wincertstore-0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0
    defaults::setuptools-41.0.1-py36_0
    defaults::wheel-0.33.4-py36_0
    defaults::pip-19.1.1-py36_0

INFO conda.core.link:__init__(172): initializing UnlinkLinkTransaction with
  target_prefix: C:\Users\lamei\.conda\envs\py36
  unlink_precs:

  link_precs:
    defaults::vs2015_runtime-14.15.26706-h3a45250_4
    defaults::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
    defaults::sqlite-3.28.0-he774522_0
    defaults::python-3.6.8-h9f7ef89_7
    defaults::certifi-2019.6.16-py36_0
    defaults::wincertstore-0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0
    defaults::setuptools-41.0.1-py36_0
    defaults::wheel-0.33.4-py36_0
    defaults::pip-19.1.1-py36_0

DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:__init__(604): instantiating ProgressiveFetchExtract with
  defaults::vc-14.1-h0510ff6_4
  defaults::pip-19.1.1-py36_0
  defaults::sqlite-3.28.0-he774522_0
  defaults::setuptools-41.0.1-py36_0
  defaults::python-3.6.8-h9f7ef89_7
  defaults::certifi-2019.6.16-py36_0
  defaults::wincertstore-0.2-py36h7fe50ca_0
  defaults::wheel-0.33.4-py36_0
  defaults::vs2015_runtime-14.15.26706-h3a45250_4

DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.test:file_path_is_writable(31): [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\pkgs\\urls.txt'
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_check_writable(261): package cache directory 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs' writable: False
DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:_make_single_record(313): unable to read C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\pip-19.1.1-py36_0\info\repodata_record.json
  because IOError(2, 'No such file or directory')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 868, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 741, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 465, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 329, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
Logged from file package_cache_data.py, line 324
```

Comment: Trying running with a verbose flag - DEBUG mode (`-vv`) should be sufficient to see if it's still working on something; TRACE mode (`-vvv`) is probably overkill.  Don't run as admin - Conda is designed to avoid all that.  Please add `conda info` output to the question.

Comment: How do I run with a verbose flag?

Comment: add `-vv` to your command.

Comment: I get 
'-vv' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: When you get an error like that, you need to respond with the command you typed, not just the result. Should be: `conda create -vv --name py36 python=3.6`

Comment: I get stuck again. I edited the question to specify it.

Comment: Looks like you're hitting permissions errors, so maybe you do need to run as admin. When you originally installed, did you choose to install for "All Users"? The recommended install is "Just Me".

Comment: Yes I did for all users. Could that cause problems even if I run as admin? Running as admin gets me stuck with the same thing except with the additional line `DEBUG conda.gateways.disk.create:extract_tarball(209): extracting C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\pip-19.1.1-py36_0.conda
  to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\pkgs\pip-19.1.1-py36_0`